# how to have two template tags {{ form | safe }} + |crispy equals to?

Tags: django

I need to use `safe` and `crispy` on my form, how do I use both of them? 
I tried `{{form |safe |crispy}}`

it doesn't work

Comment: What does "doesn't work" entail? errors? invalid results? what is it you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite

```
{{form|safe|crispy}}
```

as

```
{% with tempform=form|safe %}
{{tempform|crispy}}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: this doesn't work but aprt from this |safe isn''t working anymore just when I do {{form|safe}} do you know why?